# How to perform SSO using Discourse and Auth0?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, single-sign-on, auth0, discourse

I am using trying to perform SSO using Auth0 for wordPress and discourse from my own application. the flow is mentioned below.

[Image added here (low on rep) so cant post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0dOA.png)

The user enters user name and password in the application, the details are sent to the server which authenticates the user with the auth0 API and send back the token.

I have installed auth0 SSO plugin2 from GitHub in Discourse and all the client ID, client secrets are added to the plugin.

I want to know who to perform SSO in case of Discourse when I have logged into my application.

For WordPress were are using the following method.

```
<form *ngIf="userService.isAuthenticated()" ngNoForm action="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/index.php?auth0=implicit&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&connection=xxxxxxxxxx"
    method="post">
    <input class="hidden" type="text" id="token" name="token" value="{{tokenValueIsHereReturnedbyAuth0Authentication}}" />
    <input class="hidden" type="text" id="redirect_to" name="redirect_to" value="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/index.html" />
    <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="View" />
</form>
```

So How to do similar thing in discourse?

I have tried the following

1. https://meta.discourse.org/t/official-single-sign-on-for-discourse/13045?u=deanmarktaylor

However i could not complete that as I do not know what is

`https://somesite.com/sso?sso=PAYLOAD&sig=SIG`

PAYLOAD and SIG is

Update:

The payload i think: what Auth0 gave me as access_token is the payload, which is encoded as `Base64` (using: base64encode dot org) and SIG is a HMAC-SHA256 hash of the payload using sso_secret as the key and Base64 encoded payload 
(freeformatter dot com slash hmac-generator)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my blog post about how to integrate a seamless SSO using Auth0 with Discourse.

You will basically need to set up a new [Auth0 Rule](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/current) that uses an already developed library that supports Discourse way to sign requests. Using your Client ID and Client Secret, copy and paste the code for that rule and bring a better way to handle SSO without using any extra plugin. Nice and easy :)

https://medium.com/leog-s-blog/discourse-sso-with-auth0-e49486d0294a